# Grouping on Weeks

Tags: mysql, group-by, week-number

I want to show the open and close counts of selected date range from filter. The data will be grouped on Organization Product,Month and Week. But the problem is when  I calculate the open and close weeks. Open has a separate column and close has different.. It can group it on any single field like i want this :

```
Week             Open         Close

0                  3            5
1                  2            0
```

If date of Close is not in week 2 .And date of open exists in week 2 it should show like :

```
Week          Open      Close

2              3          0
```

How can I Group it on both column?

Please help.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. If you want to have the total amount of open and close per week you can use:
`SELECT SUM(open) AS totalOpen, SUM(close) AS totalClose FROM table GROUP BY week`. And consider renaming 'week' to something else, since it's also a MySQL function.

Comment: You should share your query.

Comment: I m using mysql week function for calculating week. But the problem is it asks for column field . Which is different for both open and close columns so which field should I use in it. Im using WEEK(datefield,5) -
WEEK(DATE_SUB(datefield, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(datefield)-1 DAY),5) as Week for calculating week. Both open and close giving different number of weeks depending on their values

Answer (score 0):

An example how to group by open and close weeks.

```
SELECT Organization, Product, Month, 
       week, 
       sum(open) AS open,
       sum(close) AS close
FROM (

    SELECT Organization, Product, Month, 
           open_week AS week, 
           count(*) AS open,
           0 AS close
    FROM tab
    GROUP BY Organization, Product, Month, open_week

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Organization, Product, Month, 
           close_week AS week, 
           0 AS open,
           count(*) AS close
    FROM tab
    GROUP BY Organization, Product, Month, close_week

) alias
GROUP BY Organization, Product, Month, week
ORDER BY Organization, Product, Month, week
```

demo included --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01ac3/1

For the sake of simplicity, the example is using `month`, `close_week` and `open_week` 
instead of functions like this:
 `WEEK(datefield,5) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(datefield, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(datefield)-1 DAY),5)`